# Sharepoint 2010 : web.ProcessBatchData is throwing the error

Tags: sharepoint

i am facing an issue while trying to migrate the data from one list to other, the list is having custom columns which are of type "Single line of Text","Multiple line of Text","Person or Group","Datetime","Integer".
i am getting the below error after execution of the statement "Web.ProcessBatchData"

.....

The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred.

(Result Code: 0x80020005)
The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred.

(Result Code: 0x800704c7)

2147023673">
......

Can someone please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Can you identify what column fails by removing one by one and than post the content of the failing column?